# Accessing UWP Child Element Programmatically from Other Class

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP XAML named **MyPage.xaml** like below

```
<Page
    x:Class="AffiliaTool.Lib.View.BrowserWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:local="using:AffiliaTool.Lib.View"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:tk="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:vm="using:AffiliaTool.Lib.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <tk:TabView x:Name="TabViewBar" />
</Page>
```

And from **other class**, I want to instantiate that class and manipulate TabView programmatically like below

```
var mypage = new MyPage();
mypage.TabViewBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I used to be able to access **Child element** programmatically from **other class** when coding WPF, but why can't I do that in UWP but from codebehind? Anyway to go around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Just add a `FieldModifier` like this:

```
<tk:TabView x:Name="TabViewBar" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

then you can access TabViewBar from another class.

Hope that helps.